# Could someone explain what this vectors proof is asking me?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I just started learning about vectors and need to solve this proof. I would begin to make an attempt to prove it, but I'm confused at what the actual question is even asking. So far all I am understanding is that I need to show that a change of Matrix $M_{n1}$ to $M_{m1}$ is a linear transformation. These questions were much easier to understand before vectors were involved so I was wondering if someone could help me understand it so I could try to solve it.

Original Question -

Let $U$ and $V$ be vector spaces, and let $L: U \to V$ be a function from $U$ to $V$. We say that $L$ is a “linear transformation,” if the following conditions are satisfied for all scalars $k$ and for all vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ in $U$:

a. $L(\vec{u} + \vec{v}) = L(\vec{u}) + L(\vec{v})$

b. $L(k\vec{u}) = kL(\vec{u})$

Show that for any $ \in M_{}$, the function $L: _{n1} → _{m1}$ defined for all vectors $\vec{u} \in M_{1}$ by
$L(\vec{u}) = A \vec{u}$
is a linear transformation.

Comment: They want you to prove that the function L satisfies conditions a. and b. (for all values of k, u and v).

Answer (score 1):

This isn´t that hard once that you are used to the idea of linear tramsformations. You only have to proove that L satisfies conditions a) and b), you just have to put your hands on it. You have that $$\begin{align*}L:M_{n1}&\to M_{m1}
\\u&\mapsto Au\end{align*},$$ then take $u,v$ vectors and check a) and then b) with some scalar $k$.